# How to build a vanilla nodejs frontend app?

Tags: node.js, express, npm, yaml, aws-amplify

I am trying to deploy a vanilla nodejs frontend application on AWS Amplify . The prebuild phase complete without problem but the deployment just block at the build phase.

In local, I run my app with `node app.js`, so in my `amplify.yml` I have the following configuration :

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm install
    build:
      commands:
        - node app.js
  artifacts:
    # IMPORTANT - Please verify your build output directory
    baseDirectory: /
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

The amplify build log says:

```
     # Starting phase: preBuild
                                 # Executing command: npm install
2022-05-25T20:31:21.097Z [WARNING]: npm
2022-05-25T20:31:21.098Z [WARNING]: WARN app@1.0.0 No description
2022-05-25T20:31:21.102Z [WARNING]: npm
2022-05-25T20:31:21.102Z [WARNING]: WARN app@1.0.0 No repository field.
2022-05-25T20:31:21.103Z [WARNING]: 
2022-05-25T20:31:21.402Z [INFO]: audited 484 packages in 2.108s
2022-05-25T20:31:21.510Z [INFO]: 28 packages are looking for funding
                                 run `npm fund` for details
2022-05-25T20:31:21.510Z [INFO]: found 17 vulnerabilities (4 moderate, 10 high, 3 critical)
                                 run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
2022-05-25T20:31:21.577Z [INFO]: # Completed phase: preBuild
                                 # Starting phase: build
                                 # Executing command: node app.js
2022-05-25T20:31:22.404Z [INFO]: Server started on port 5000
```

But the build is still ongoing despite the app is running apparently.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Doesn't the build have to _finish_ at some point? You're starting the app in the build phase, so it never actually gets deployed.

Comment: My problem is I don't know what command to enter for build. In local environment I don't need to build I just do `node app.js` to start the app. What I am supposed to do to build the app for production ?

Comment: We don't know, we can't see your app - is there any transpilation or bundling? Maybe you don't need to do _anything_.

Comment: Nothing, this is just a vanilla nodejs frontent app. html page are served with ejs. I just run node app.js to start the app. Nothing more.

Comment: Then it's entirely feasible you don't need _any_ build step here.

Comment: Yes I removed the build but after I get an error message : `No index.html detected in deploy folder \codebuild\ etc.`

Comment: Please give a [mre] - it's unclear whether you _expected_ that file to exist in that directory, or why starting the app might create it.

Comment: OK now I just created an empty index.html at the root of my project folder. So that fixed the above error, however now my deployment is done but it's a blank page. It's pretty normal since the index.html is my landing page. But how to make my app.js to be the entry point ? Is there a line I can add in the amplify.yml ?